# Help with Formula Text Field that Looks at 2 other fields

Tags: formula-field

I have a formula text field on the opportunity object that should display 4 different things depending on the value of 2 different fields. Partner_ID__r.Type is a picklist field on the Account object and Partner_ID__r.Name is a text field on the Account object. When Partner ID - Type is "Partner," populate this new field with "Partner". When the Partner ID - name contains "SmartBiz," populate this new field with "Organic." When the Partner ID - Type is "Bank Customer," populate this new field with "Bank Customer." Otherwise, populate the field with "Other". Below is what I have tried but I am getting the error "syntax error."

```
IF(ISPICKVAL(Partner_ID__r.Type , "Partner”),”Partner",
IF(CONTAINS(Partner_ID__r.Name , "SmartBiz”),”Organic",
IF(ISPICKVAL(Partner_ID__r.Type , "Bank Customer”),”Bank Customer”,
"Other")))
```

Comment: You've given us a description of what you're trying to do, and what you've tried so far, but you haven't told us what the issue is. You should [edit] your question to explain what's wrong. Giving us some examples of input, the observed output, and your expected output would help.

Comment: Also, you should go back to your earlier questions and accept answers that helped you. Accepting an answer signals to the community that your issue has been resolved and signals to others that the marked answer is likely to be correct.

Comment: I just provided the error I am seeing when I click button "check syntax"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strings in Salesforce don't use double quotes or smart quotes.

Replace all of them with single quotes (`'`)

bad: `"SmartBiz”`
good: `'SmartBiz'`

Comment: this worked, thanks!!